# How to sort spark DataFrame by Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] in descending order?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There is a DataFrame as following:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = List(
  ("id1","blue","1")
  ,("id2","red","2")
  ,("id3","red","3")
  ,("id4","blue","3")
  ,("id4","green","3")
).toDF("id", "color", "size")

+---+-----+----+
| id|color|size|
+---+-----+----+
|id1| blue|   1|
|id2|  red|   2|
|id3|  red|   3|
|id4| blue|   3|
|id4|green|   3|
+---+-----+----+
```

There is a Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] and it can sort `df` as following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val col = Seq(new Column("size"), new Column("color"))
df.sort(col:_*).show
```

But I want to sort by `col` with descending order.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc
```

`df.sort(desc(col:_*))` does not work.

Then how to sort `df` by `col` in descending order?

Comment: You can apply `asc`/`desc` for sorting on individual columns, like, `val col = Seq(new Column("size").asc, new Column("color").desc)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `col.map(_.desc)` to construct the sorting expressions with `desc` ordering:

```
val col = Seq(new Column("size"), new Column("color"))

// ascending
df.sort(col: _*).show
+---+-----+----+
| id|color|size|
+---+-----+----+
|id1| blue|   1|
|id2|  red|   2|
|id4| blue|   3|
|id4|green|   3|
|id3|  red|   3|
+---+-----+----+

// descending
df.sort(col.map(_.desc): _*).show
+---+-----+----+
| id|color|size|
+---+-----+----+
|id3|  red|   3|
|id4|green|   3|
|id4| blue|   3|
|id2|  red|   2|
|id1| blue|   1|
+---+-----+----+
```

Here `col.map(_.desc)` returns a list of expressions:

```
col.map(_.desc)
// res2: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = 
//       List(size DESC NULLS LAST, color DESC NULLS LAST)
```